# Equivalent of GETDATE() BETWEEN Two DateTime Fields where Both can be NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[DateOnline] --Nullable
      ,[DateOffline] --Nullable
      ,[PageId]
      ,[DownloadId]
      ,[Weight]
  FROM [DownloadPage]
  WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN [DateOnline] AND [DateOffline]
```

Equivalent to:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[DateOnline] --Nullable
      ,[DateOffline] --Nullable
      ,[PageId]
      ,[DownloadId]
      ,[Weight]
  FROM [DownloadPage]
  WHERE ([DateOnline] IS NULL OR [DateOnline] <= GETDATE())
  AND ([DateOffline] IS NULL OR [DateOffline] > GETDATE())
```

But with also catering for NULLs?

Or is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Where are parentheses needed here?

Thanks.

EDIT:

**Both [DateOnline] AND [DateOffline] are of type DateTime**

**If [DateOnline] is NULL then the logic is "online now"**

**If [DateOffline] is NULL then the logic is "never go offline (once online)"**

Sorry, I should have included this in my question to begin with.

Comment: Your parenthesis are needed for your query. And I actually think that this is the right way to do what you want if you have any indexes on your date columns

Comment: I agree with @Lamak. Also, the `>` should be `>=` for the query to simulate `BETWEEN`

Comment: @ypercube I'm not so sure about changing > to >= as in my tests when the second part of GETDATE() e.g. second = x and the second part of [DateOffline] also = x then the row was not returned.

Comment: @Chris: I was just pointing on the equivalence. If you have a datetime (like the `GETDATE()` and you want to check if it is in a date range, yes I agree, I'd use `WHERE DateStart <= DateTime AND DateTime < DateEnd` (or `DateEndColumn + 1 Day`)

Comment: But I suspect your 2 columns are `DATETIME` and not `DATE`. This complicates matters a bit.

Comment: @ypercube Sorry for the confusion, I should have said - I was testing BETWEEN with GETDATE() and trying to work out whether to use > or >= and because the row was not returned when the seconds part of GETDATE = the seconds part of [DateOffline] I believed that it was correct to use > and not >=.

Comment: You may have some rows not returned, datetimes are more accurate than seconds.

Comment: @ypercube Yeah I realise now that DateTime fields have millisecond accuracy. So I should have tested where millisecond of GETDATE() = millisecond of [DateOffline] also -1/+1 millisecond to understand how it works but I'm not gonna bother (although I am a bit OCD that way). I'll take it as read that BETWEEN is inclusive of start date and end date, however I think the way that it is in the OP makes more sense (OCD again!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author's second query will net better performance even if there is no indexes on those columns.  If there are indexes, that's a no brainer... using coalesce will disable the index and do a table scan instead of index seek (very bad for performance).

Even if there aren't any indexes on those columns, "is null" will return a constant... whereas, in the case of coalesce function, the NULL values will still need to be evaluated each time.  If you have a table full of NULL DateOnline and DateOffline, this performance leak cannot be ignored.

In any case, I can't think of a reason why you'd use coalesce in this case.

Also, I'm guessing (since you're checking date range) that those two dates are all or nothing. You probably only have to check for one of those dates.

```
 WHERE ([DateOnline] IS NULL)
 OR GETDATE() BETWEEN [DateOnline] AND [DateOffline]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `COALESCE` to convert nulls into a meaningful value.  In this example I've chose default values that will always be inside the valid range.

```
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN COALESCE([DateOnline] , '1900-01-01')
                    AND COALESCE([DateOffline], '2099-12-31')
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/def09/1

Comment: If there are any indexes on `DateOnline` or `DateOffline` then this query won't take advantage of them. Op's current query should perform better on this case

Comment: This will break for the birthdate of my grandpa and for dates after 2099. Why not `'0001-01-01'` and `'9999-12-31'` ?

Comment: @ypercube: Heh, yes. I was applying some context clues, i.e., these appear to be dates for websites, which I doubt existed before 1900, or will apply after 2099... Also, I believe if this is a normal `datetime`, field type, it is limited to a minimum value of `1753-01-01`.

Comment: I would say what you have already is more readable and better for the optimizer. Try not to use functions in the where clause if possible.

Comment: @samyi: You mean functions on indexed columns of course. There is no harm in using `GETDATE() < column` or `DATEADD(GETDATE(), ...) < column`

Comment: If they are `DATETIME` then you should use the format `YYYYMMDD` since its the only one that's not ambiguous. If they were `DATE` (I thought they were), then `YYYY-MM-DD` its not ambiguous (though I still recommend the use of `YYYYMMDD`) and it goes from `0001-01-01` through `9999-12-31`

Comment: @samyi - And if they are indexed columns, then its not better for the optimizer. Though it is more readable

Comment: @mellamokb Sorry I'm of the traditional software development type - hardcoding is a crime! I'm thinking of the Y2K bug...